# Java parenthesis order {[()]}

Tags: java, arrays, replace

There are a lot of questions concerning how to check if parenthesis are balanced, with many answers. But how do I find out the order of the parenthesis? For example `{}` should be first before `[]`, and `[]` should be before `()`. Can anyone help me form a method that will do this for me?

```
String parenthesis = "([{}])"
```

At this point I was thinking of using an `ArrayList<String>` type but what if I had jargon in between `(6[6{6}6]6)?` I know how to check for `charAt(0)`, but thats as far as my knowledge goes. Any tips would be nice.

`(6[6{6}6]6)` should turn to `{6[6(6)6]6}` with the stuff in between unchanged. And also since its based on user input in a scanner class, please show me a method that will not limit the character length.

Comment: In java each of those types of "parentheses" has a very specific and individual meaning. There is no specific order when nesting them except "do it right."

Comment: That's not the question I asked, this is just so i can read from a string the parentheses. ((())) is less readable than {[()]}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for this task.  Here's an example of how this could be implemented:

```
parenthesis.matches(".*\\(.*\\[.*\\{.*\\}.*\\].*\\).*")
```

This will return `true` if the different parentheses are balanced as you described in your question, and `false` if not.  If you want to automatically fix these errors, you could write a replace operation:

```
parenthesis = parenthesis.replaceAll("(.*)[{\\[(](.*)[{\\[(](.*)[{\\[(](.*)[}\\])](.*)[}\\])](.*)[}\\])](.*)", "$1{$2[$3($4)$5]$6}$7");
```

This replaces all the different types of parentheses with the correct types, and preserves the content in between.

If you want to have your program check for more advanced stuff, your idea of using `ArrayList`s sounds like the best plan.  If you want to allow multiple levels of nesting, so there could only be two levels, but there could also be three, and you want to allow blocks to be re-opened (i.e. `(a{b}c{d}e)`), I would use the following piece of code.  Note that this is much more complex than the two regex options above, and if you can make some assumptions, there may be stuff you can cut out of it.  Be sure to read the comments, as they explain each line of code:

```
String parenthesis = "{a[b]c}(d)[e]"; //test string
ArrayList<Character> currentlyOpen = new ArrayList<>(); //all currently open parenthesis types
ArrayList<Character> opens = new ArrayList<>(); //all used open parenthesis types
Stack<Character> closes = new Stack<>(); //all used close parenthesis types
String[] openOrder = new String[] { "{", "[", "(" }; //correct open parenthesis order
String[] closeOrder = new String[] { ")", "]", "}" }; //correct close parenthesis order
Matcher regex = Pattern.compile("[{\\[()\\]}]").matcher(parenthesis); //match any open or close parenthesis type
ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>(); //list of the separate top-level groups
int removedChars = 0; //to keep track of index in the input string

while (!parenthesis.isEmpty()) {
    while (regex.find()) { //iterate over all regex matches
        char c = regex.group().charAt(0); //get the matched character

        switch (c) {
            case '}':
                if (currentlyOpen.get(currentlyOpen.size() - 1) == '{') { //if the last currently open parenthesis is the correct type
                    currentlyOpen.remove(currentlyOpen.size() - 1); //remove this open parenthesis type from the currently open list (it is now closed)

                    if (!closes.contains(c)) {
                        closes.add(c); //add this parenthesis type to the closed parenthesis list if it's not already there
                    }

                    break;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("unbalanced"); //else cough and die (or you could return false or -1 or something)
            case ']': //same as the above case
                if (currentlyOpen.get(currentlyOpen.size() - 1) == '[') {
                    currentlyOpen.remove(currentlyOpen.size() - 1);

                    if (!closes.contains(c)) {
                        closes.add(c);
                    }

                    break;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("unbalanced");
            case ')': //same as the above case
                if (currentlyOpen.get(currentlyOpen.size() - 1) == '(') {
                    currentlyOpen.remove(currentlyOpen.size() - 1);

                    if (!closes.contains(c)) {
                        closes.add(c);
                    }

                    break;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("unbalanced");
            default: //if this is an open parenthesis
                if (!opens.contains(c)) {
                    opens.add(c); //add this to the "all open parentheses" list if it's not already there
                }

                currentlyOpen.add(c); //add this to the "currently open parethesis" list
        }

        if (currentlyOpen.isEmpty()) { //if we are back at the top level
            parts.add(parenthesis.substring(0, regex.end() - removedChars)); //add the top-level group to the list
            parenthesis = parenthesis.substring(regex.end() - removedChars); //remove the top-level group from the input string
            removedChars = regex.end(); //update removedChars
            break; //break out of the loop and process this top-level group only
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < opens.size(); i++) { //iterate over all the open parentheses used
        parts.set(parts.size() - 1, parts.get(parts.size() - 1).replace(opens.get(i).toString(), Character.toString((char) i))); //replace them all with intermediate characters (in this case numbers, you could use something else)
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < opens.size(); i++) { //iterate over all the open res again
        parts.set(parts.size() - 1, parts.get(parts.size() - 1).replace(Character.toString((char) i), openOrder[i + openOrder.length - opens.size()])); //this time replace all the intermediate characters with the proper parentheses
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < closes.size(); i++) { //do the same thing for close parentheses
        parts.set(parts.size() - 1, parts.get(parts.size() - 1).replace(closes.get(i).toString(), Character.toString((char) i)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < closes.size(); i++) { //do the same thing for close parentheses
        parts.set(parts.size() - 1, parts.get(parts.size() - 1).replace(Character.toString((char) i), closeOrder[i]));
    }

    opens.clear(); //reset the list of open parenthesis types
    closes.clear(); //reset the list of close parenthesis types
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //use a string builder to put all the parts together again
parts.forEach(sb::append); //append all the parts to the string builder
String res = sb.toString(); //get the string from the string builder
System.out.println(res); //print it out so you can see it
```

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems."

Comment: I'm curious why you think using regex creates "two problems".  Regex works in one line, and is very expandable if the OP later realizes they have further constraints.

Comment: I'm not to sure on this, but wouldn't your regex code allow ([)]?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not about including all () [] {}, but rather I was asking about userinput. The user could define all three types, two types, or one type.

Comment: You are correct in both of your questions.  Those are some of the assumptions I made when writing the regex.  I have updated my answer to check for more complex inputs, but this makes the program much longer.

Comment: Pretty good, but you did not take user input into suggestion. But following what you have now I may have enough information to solve user input. My string variable isn't just one string, its an equation like PEMDAS. The reason to order the parentheses is to solve higher order {} before lower order [], (). Ascending to descending. For me to do that I need to calculate the blance of parentheses, which I have. And the order of many parentheses, not just one set. But thanks much.

Comment: User input can be obtained with a scanner object and calling `parenthesis = scanner.nextLine()`.  And no problem!

Comment: I meant when a user types for example: {8}(9)[9], it should be un altered. With your code it converts it into {8)[9](9} which is entirely in correct, and unbalanced.

Comment: So basically if I had this ([{}])([{}]) or any other positions similar like this, the code should fix each set of parentheses individually. Like this: {[()]}{[()]}, see what I mean? And it should continue to do that until ever parentheses in the string is fixed in that matter. I should note something like {9[9(9{9[9(9)9]9}9)9]9} Should also be unchanged for it is in the correct manner, although probably nontraditional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215341/discussion-between-charlie-armstrong-and-jobobjo).

Answer (score 0):

If they have to be balanced for your example string, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^][(){}]*` to not match any of the brackets in between.

```
^\(([^]\[(){}]*)\[([^]\[(){}]*){([^]\[(){}]*)}([^]\[(){}]*)\]([^]\[(){}]*)\)$
```

*In Java*

```
String regex = "^\\(([^][()\\{}]*)\\[([^][()\\{}]*)\\{([^][()\\{}]*)\\}([^][()\\{}]*)\\]([^][()\\{}]*)\\)$";
```

*In parts*

```
^               Start of string
\(              Match ( char
(               Capture group 1
  [^]\[(){}]*   Match any of the listed and repeat 0 or more times
)               Close group
\[              Match [ char
(               Capture group 2
  [^]\[(){}]*   Match any of the listed and repeat 0 or more times
)               Close group
{               Match { char
(               Capture group 3
  [^]\[(){}]*   Match any of the listed and repeat 0 or more times
)               Close group
}               Match } char
(               Capture group 4
  [^]\[(){}]*   Match any of the listed and repeat 0 or more times
)               Close group
\]              Match ] char
(               Capture group 5
  [^]\[(){}]*   Match any of the listed and repeat 0 or more times
)               Close group
\)              Match ) char
$               End of string
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRwc29/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OJH4d7)

In the replacement use `{$1[$2($3)$4]$5}`

Comment: What does unclosed character mean?

Comment: By that I mean for example this `(6[6{6)))}6]6)` where there are multiple `))) ` this pattern allows only `([{}])` and any char other than the used braces in between.

Comment: I get a PatternSyntaxException stating that there is an unclosed character near index 78.

Comment: @jobobjo Did you use the pattern from the demo?  https://ideone.com/OJH4d7

Comment: Okay it works, but I still have a problem when there's more or less parenthesis. Such as ([]) is not converted.

Comment: You could make the `[]` and `{}` optional and check which groups are not empty. Then do the replacement for the groups that you have. https://regex101.com/r/h1sJ8r/1